# Tikz error "giving up on this path"

Tags: forest, splitargument

I have a strange `giving up on this path, did you forget a semicolon?` + `missing } inserted` bug with one of my commands made from `tikz` code (the code itself is perfectly working, suggested to me by `Sandy G`, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670836/262813; the mistake comes from my command).

The `\coolbrace` command causes an error if another `\draw` command, here a control arrow, is added afterwards; but if the arrow is first drawn, no bug happens. Any idea where the mistake lies?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolbraceauxone}{mmmmmmm}{ 
    \draw[decorate,semithick,decoration={brace,amplitude=#1pt}]([shift={(#3,#4)}]#6.north east)--node[sloped, above=#2pt, align=center]{#5}([shift={(#3+0.9,#4)}]#7.south east);}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolbraceaux}{mmmmm>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{%
    \coolbraceauxone{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}#6}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolbrace}{O{}mm}
{
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn {coolbrace} {#1}
    \coolbrace:VVVVVnn
    \coolbrace_size
    \coolbrace_above
    \coolbrace_xshift
    \coolbrace_yshift
    \coolbrace_text
    {#2}
    {#3}
    \group_end:
}
\keys_define:nn {coolbrace}
{
    size.tl_set:N =     \coolbrace_size,
    above.tl_set:N = \coolbrace_above,
    xshift.tl_set:N = \coolbrace_xshift,
    yshift.tl_set:N = \coolbrace_yshift,
    text.tl_set:N = \coolbrace_text,
    size.initial:n = 8,
    above.initial:n = 10,
    xshift.initial:n = 0,
    yshift.initial:n = 0.4,
    text.initial:n = ~,}

\cs_set_eq:NN\coolbrace:nnnnnnn\coolbraceaux

\cs_generate_variant:Nn\coolbrace:nnnnnnn{VVVVV}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{forest}
        [ASP,name=pol[\textit{subject},name=subject][Asp 
        [asp][POL
        [AdvP[\textit{non},roof]][Pol, name=nab
        [pol][aP
        [~,name=arg][a'
        [a][root]]]]]]]
        \draw[dashed,->,>=stealth] (arg)..controls +(west:2) and +(south west:2)..(subject);
        \coolbrace[text=Adjective]{pol,nab}% No problem here.
 % The following order triggers a bug:
    %\coolbrace[text=Adjective]{pol,nab}
    %\draw[dashed,->,>=stealth] (arg)..controls +(west:2) and +(south west:2)..(subject);
    \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably some unintended behavior with the `forest` parser. As a workaround you can add an useless `;` after the `coolbrace` command.

Comment: The problem is not related to the `forest` parser. It persists in a `tikzpicture` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the definition of `\coolbrace`, which is defined to take two mandatory arguments, but receives only one.

Here's a correct definition of `\coolbrace`.  (It fixes the argument-related issues in the auxiliary macros as well.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolbraceauxone}{mmmmmmm}{ 
    \draw[decorate,semithick,decoration={brace,amplitude=#1pt}]([shift={(#3,#4)}]#6.north east)--node[sloped, above=#2pt, align=center]{#5}([shift={(#3+0.9,#4)}]#7.south east);}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolbraceaux}{mmmmm>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{%
    \coolbraceauxone{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}#6}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolbrace}{O{}m}
{
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn {coolbrace} {#1}
    \coolbrace:VVVVVn
    \coolbrace_size
    \coolbrace_above
    \coolbrace_xshift
    \coolbrace_yshift
    \coolbrace_text
    {#2}
    \group_end:
}
\keys_define:nn {coolbrace}
{
    size.tl_set:N =     \coolbrace_size,
    above.tl_set:N = \coolbrace_above,
    xshift.tl_set:N = \coolbrace_xshift,
    yshift.tl_set:N = \coolbrace_yshift,
    text.tl_set:N = \coolbrace_text,
    size.initial:n = 8,
    above.initial:n = 10,
    xshift.initial:n = 0,
    yshift.initial:n = 0.4,
    text.initial:n = ~,}

\cs_set_eq:NN\coolbrace:nnnnnn\coolbraceaux

\cs_generate_variant:Nn\coolbrace:nnnnnn{VVVVVn}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

    \begin{forest}
        [ASP,name=pol[\textit{subject},name=subject][Asp 
        [asp][POL
        [AdvP[\textit{non},roof]][Pol, name=nab
        [pol][aP
        [~,name=arg][a'
        [a][root]]]]]]]
        % \draw[dashed,->,>=stealth] (arg)..controls +(west:2) and +(south west:2)..(subject);
        % \coolbrace[text=Adjective]{pol,nab}% No problem here.
 % The following order triggers a bug:
    \coolbrace[text=Adjective]{pol,nab}
    \draw[dashed,->,>=stealth] (arg)..controls +(west:2) and +(south west:2)..(subject);
    \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the debug, I corrected `egreg`'s answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670023/262813.